# How to match multiple occurrences of a substring

Tags: regex

If I have an HTML string such as:

```
<div><p>£20<span class="abc" /><span class="def">56</span></p></div>
```

And I want the text:

```
20<span class="abc" /><span class="def">56
```

How do I define a regular expression to match the **target sections multiple times**. So far I have:

```
str.match(/\d*<[^>]*>\d*/)
```

But this will only return the first number section `20<span class="abc" />`

I need this to be flexible to match multiple tag / numeric sections while trimming anything leading or trailing the first / last digit in the string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To match multiple times use to need use the global option

```
str.match(/your_expression_here/g)
                                ^
```

Answer (score 10):

Adding `/g` isn't enough if you wish to match multiple occurrences of a substring. If that's the case, reluctant quantifiers may be used as described herein.

Given the string:

```
<div><p>£20<span class="abc" /><span class="def">56</span></p></div>
```

You will arrive at the text you wanted using:

```
\d+.*>\d+
```

But given the same string repeated two times:

```
<div><p>£20<span class="abc" /><span class="def">56</span></p></div><div><p>£20<span class="abc" /><span class="def">56</span></p></div>
```

You will not find the target selection multiple times. You'll only find it once due to the greedy nature of `.*`. To make `.*` non-greedy, or reluctant, simply add a `?` after the `*` and you will arrive at:

```
\d+.*?>\d+
```

Which will find both occurrences of the substring you asked for as [shown here](https://regexr.com/45pfl).

Answer (score 1):

Just allow the group to be repeated: `(?:...)+` means "Match `...` 1 or more times:

```
str.match(/\d+(?:<[^>]*>)+\d+/)
```

As per Alan Moore's suggestion, I've also changed the `\d*` into `\d+`, making the numbers required instead of optional.

Comment: While you're at it, change each `\d*` to `\d+`; that's got to be a mistake.