# Regex.exec shows only first occurence

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

Im using the following regex:

```
\b([a-zäöüßA-ZÄÖÜ][^\s]*)
```

For the String "Choriner Straße 12" its matching "Choriner Straße", if i test it for example at regex101. this is exactly what I need.
But if I use it in my code with

```
regex.exec("Choriner Straße 12")
```

The code:

```
const street_regex = new RegExp('\\b([a-zäöüßA-ZÄÖÜ][^\\s]*)/g');
```

Its returning just "Choriner". I dont know whats wrong... can you help me please?

Comment: try adding /g in the end.

Comment: not working, because its not matching... this is the code: const street_regex = new RegExp('\\b([a-zäöüßA-ZÄÖÜ][^\\s]*)/g');

Comment: lemme play with it real quick.

Comment: Could be \b([a-zäöüßA-ZÄÖÜ0-9][^\s]*) but I'm not really sure what you're trying to extract, like from which context. Can you give me more information on that? Like what is the whole string and what you're trying to extract?

Comment: Also notes: you are matching with a group, which means .exec will return array containing the matches.

Comment: Don't use the `new RegExp` constructor unless you have to construct the pattern from a variable - otherwise, use a regex literal.

Comment: I want the whole string bu without the house number in this case. The number could be in front of the string or after it. but i only want the street name (choriner) and the string "Straße" after it. But instead of "Straße" it could be somthing else. like avenue or street or something like that.

Comment: See [How do I retrieve all matches for a regular expression in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323417/how-do-i-retrieve-all-matches-for-a-regular-expression-in-javascript). Use `RegExp#exec` in a loop with a `g` regex. Or, `s.match(/..../g)`, see [How to match multiple occurrences of string within a string using reg ex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7041308/how-to-match-multiple-occurrences-of-string-within-a-string-using-reg-ex)

Comment: Can you try this one? /(\S+).+(?=\s\d.+)/igm
EDIT: this seems more correct way if numbers can be at the beginning:

Comment: /(?![\s\d].+).+?(\S+).+(?=\s\d.+)/igm

Answer (score 1):

See [the MDN documentation for the RegExp function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

> ```
> new RegExp(pattern[, flags])
> ```

Flags need to be passed as a second argument, nor with `/FLAGS` at the end of the expression.

```
const street_regex = new RegExp('\\b([a-zäöüßA-ZÄÖÜ][^\\s]*)', 'g');
```

… but you shouldn't be using the RegExp constructor function in the first place. The string escaping makes it horrible to try to read, and it provides no benefits over a simple regexp literal.

```
const street_regex = /\b([a-zäöüßA-ZÄÖÜ][^\s]*)/g;
```

Comment: this is not matching anymore... Im getting null as result

Comment: withoug the global flag its: "Choriner",
            "Choriner"

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example using the `/regex/` syntax:

```
var regex = /\b([a-zäöüßA-ZÄÖÜ][^\s]*)/g

while((match = regex.exec("Choriner Straße 12")) !== null) {
    console.log('The full match object:', match);
    console.log('The actual result:', match[0]);
}
```

Comment: this is the result of your code: 0: "Choriner"
1: "Choriner" so "Straße" is missing...

Comment: That's only the contents of the first match. 0 is the full match, 1-n are any capture groups, n+1 is the index of the match, and n+2 is the original string. [See this MDN artical](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) for more information on how `RegExp.exec` works

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I get correctly from your questions, this should do.

```
const getAddressWithoutNumber = fullAddress => {
  const result = /(?![\s\d].+).+?(\S+).+(?=\s\d.+)/igm.exec(fullAddress);
  return result && result[0] || null;
}

console.log(getAddressWithoutNumber('123 Choriner Straße 12')); // outputs "Choriner Straße"
```

Comment: I am sorry, but you have to give more information. Because this works just like you asked.

Comment: street_regex.exec(parsedXls[i].Address1) !== null ? adr.push(street_regex.exec(parsedXls[i].Address1)) : -1;  this is where it is executed

Comment: street_regex.exec(parsedXls[i].Address1); should already return what you asked for with this regex and with the example you gave. See regex101 matching: https://regex101.com/r/3zF82o/1

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found out, it was not your regexes, that not work, but my code. I found the right regex but have one more problem. This is the code:

```js
const regex = /\b([a-zäöüßA-ZÄÖÜ][^\s]+)/g;
const str = `Choriner Straße 12`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    for (var i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
      console.log(i,m)
    }
}
```

This is the result on my console (the for loop):

> ["Choriner", "Choriner", index: 0, input: "Choriner Straße 12", groups: undefined]
>   runner-4.1.7.min.js:1 1 (2) ["Choriner", "Choriner", index: 0, input: "Choriner Straße 12", groups: undefined]
>   runner-4.1.7.min.js:1 0 (2) ["Straße", "Straße", index: 9, input: "Choriner Straße 12", groups: undefined]
>   runner-4.1.7.min.js:1 1 (2) ["Straße", "Straße", index: 9, input: "Choriner Straße 12", groups: undefined]

As you can see the regex matches exactly what I want, but I need the matches as onw word...