# CircleCI config filters's tags's only regex: how to use flags

Tags: circleci

I am trying to use the [`tags` filter](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#tags) for a job in CircleCI.

```yaml
workflows:
  foo:
    jobs:
      - bar:
          filters:
            tags:
              only: /\d+/
```

The `only` key of `tags` is what I am interested in.  Here's a sample regex: `/\d+/`

1. It's designed to match 1+ digits
2. Currently it doesn't match numbers with 2+ digits, because I need to add the `global` flag, `/g`

   - See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7041308/how-to-match-multiple-occurrences-of-a-substring) for why
3. The correct regex would be `/\d+/g`
4. The CircleCI docs point to [`java.util.regex` docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)
5. Which didn't help me figure out if CircleCI regex would support flags :S

**My question(s)**

- Does CircleCI regex support the use of flags?
- How can I use flags in a regex?

  - Can you provide a link to an example?
  - Will my above regex of `/\d+/g` work?

Comment: + is greedy, you should not have to use `g`. Try variations like `\d\d*` and `\d{1,}`, you might have missed something earlier.

Comment: @LJISAM see: https://javascript.info/regexp-quantifiers#shorthands, isn't `{1,}` the same as `+`?

Comment: That was the idea, yes. (pp* is also the same as p+ btw) Richard Nixon gave the correct answer, your pattern was only getting checked against the first letter of your input, and got satisfied with it (you should 'accept' his answer)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think CircleCI supports the use of flags, it doesn't seem necessary.

Looking at the example on https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/workflows/#using-regular-expressions-to-filter-tags-and-branches

You should ensure that you use `^` and `$` to encapsulate your match pattern otherwise they will early out.

e.g. `/\d+/` will match "123" but will stop as soon as the first digit is encountered, however `/^\d+$/` will not since the pattern has start/end markers.

Comment: Can you provide a few regex test cases @RichardNixon that will trigger the difference between `/\d+/` and `/^\d+$/`?  I am not the best with regex (in case you can't tell), and I think comparison test cases will clarify things

Comment: e.g. well `/\d+/` would match "middle9nine" and `/^\d+$/` would not. The latter would only match a string that is made up entirely of numbers.

Comment: Thank you @RichardNixon for the answer, it helped me find a workaround.  I can't mark it as the real answer, since it's not 100% for sure if flags are supported.